# GraphX For .Net Two DataEdges from one DataVertex to another

Tags: c#, graph, spark-graphx, graphx-net

I'm using GraphX for .Net library to build graph based on my data.
I have relations: obj1->obj2 (type1), obj2->obj3(type1), obj1->obj2(type2) 
(type1 and type2 is a type of line, which connects two objects).
I'm adding `DataVertex` this way:

```
var dataVertex = new DataVertex(obj1.Name);
dataGraph.AddVertex(dataVertex);
```

Then I'm adding `DataEdges`:

```
var dataEdge = new DataEdge(obj1, obj2) { Text = "type1" };
dataGraph.AddEdge(dataEdge);
dataEdge = new DataEdge(obj2, obj3) { Text = "type1" };
dataGraph.AddEdge(dataEdge);
dataEdge = new DataEdge(obj1, obj2) { Text = "type2" };
dataGraph.AddEdge(dataEdge);
```

But when graph is generated (I'm using `BidirectionalGraph`) I see only one relation between obj1 and obj2. What should I add to code to see both relations in generated graph? I need to see both relations and labels because they represent cables between two physical objects.
I suspect what two relations just overlay one each-other. 
If I set `allowParallelEdges` to `false`, I see only first relation, if `true` then only second relation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close.  Try setting the ParallelEdgeDistance to some value.  For example:

```
            logicCore.EnableParallelEdges = true;
            logicCore.ParallelEdgeDistance = 25;
```